navigate to Permission set summary directly from LWC
Is it possible to open Summary page direct from LWC? I tried
 this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
          type: 'standard__recordPage',
          attributes: {
              recordId: id,
              objectApiName: 'PermissionSet',
              actionName: 'view'
          },
    })
      .then(url => {
          window.open(`${url}/summary`, "_blank");
          return;
      });    

but without any success

The GenerateUrl function only works to navigate to front-end types of records, like Accounts or Opportunities. Setup objects aren't supported. In fact, there's no standard mechanism to link to anywhere in Setup. Your best option would likely be to just use the standard__webPage PageReferencce type, something like:
{
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: `/lightning/setup/PermSets/${id}/summary`
    }
}

Note the use of ` to form a template literal, allowing us to merge the variable directly into the string.

it works,  but is it possible to open it separate window ?

@pincet If you want to do that, just use window.open.

without using NavigationMixin, correct?

@pincet You can either use GenerateUrl with the object in my answer, then use window.open instead of the navigate function, or you can just use window.open directly without NavigationMixin. Either way should work.
